# Import file associations on established users (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, powershell, file-association, dism

Using the [DISM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh824855.aspx) on PowerShell you can easily export file associations on a `xml` file:

```
Dism /Online /Export-DefaultAppAssociations:C:\FILENAME.xml
```

You can import this file on a Windows image:

```
Dism /Image:C:\IMAGE_PATH /Import-DefaultAppAssociations:C:\FILENAME.xml
```

or you can import it on the current system:

```
 Dism /Online /Import-DefaultAppAssociations:C:\FILENAME.xml
```

But when you import it on the current "Online" system it will apply the associations only for new users and not to the current/active users.

How I can apply the associations to the current user?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to SysPrep that installation, after running the command, and/or creating a new image you can deploy with the added file associations.  You can also create an image from an existing system, mount that image and apply your changes, then apply the image to the existing system.  The last option of course would not effect existing users though.